# `postMessage` behaves differently in Chromium and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, firefox, web-worker

I have a piece of code that behaves differently in Chromium and Firefox.

```js
// window.js
const worker = new Worker("worker.js", { name: "1" });

// worker.js
const worker = new Worker("worker2.js", { name: "2" });
const sab = new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT));

worker.postMessage(0);
Atomics.wait(sab, 0, 0);

// worker2.js
onmessage = ({ data }) => console.log(data);
```

In Chromium, the `worker2` never receives the message because `Atomics.wait` blocks `postMessage`, but I want to send the message synchronously.

Comment: I found Chromium need to setup the worker before posting messages.

Comment: Reminds me of https://crbug.com/1076349 that I did open a couple of years ago, and that they closed as WONT_FIX but I'm not 100% sure this is the same thing. So you may want to open a new issue. Ps: [a standalone demo](https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/OJzVNWY?editors=0010).

Comment: See [crbug.com/1075645](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1075645)

Comment: Starred the issue. Now I'm afraid StackOverflow won't bring much more. I'm pretty confident there isn't any workaround to make it "truly" synchronous. Maybe you should aim at refactoring your code so that you don't need it to be synchronous?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also expect Chrome to fix this soon, because it is a very classic semaphore usage.